# How to receive MAC address in variable number of arguments in c?

Tags: c

As I have less idea on variable number of arguments in c, I couldn't find the appropriate solution for my problem.

In short my problem is I'll receive the mac address in the function which receives variable number of arguments. I want to fetch the mac address and print it in the following format
    x:x:x:x:x:x

I want formatting of mac address in the string form should take place in the function which receives variable number of arguments.

So far I have done this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void fun(int,...);


void main()
{
unsigned char array[6] = {0x00, 0x0c, 0x2a, 0xab, 0x0f, 0x3c};
fun(10,array);
}

void fun(int x,...)
{
    unsigned char *k=NULL;
    char mac[18];
    va_list list;
    va_start(list,x);
    k=va_arg(list,unsigned char *);

    snprintf(mac,18,"Mac %s",k);
    printf("Final mac is %s\n",mac);
    va_end(list);
}
```

While printing it is printing nothing. How to achieve this?

Comment: You're not converting from real data to a string representation. Since the first byte is 0x00, that's a NUL and a string terminator. Try `printf("%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]. array[4], array[5])` to see what I mean.

Comment: @Joe even though I modified first byte with 0x01 from 0x00 then also it is not working

Comment: I wouln't use variable number of arguments in first place for this problem.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the answer....your solution will work in the main function not in the function which receives variable number of arguments.

Comment: Why do you think your function is 1) receiving a variable number of arguments and 2) receiving a string?  It's receiving neither. You're passing it a single `unsigned char[]`, which is passed as a `char *`.  You're *not* passing it a string.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Sorry I didn't follow what you have said......If you see in the main function I have called the function fun(10,array) where array is having mac in hex values....

Comment: Unrelated: but please `snprintf(mac,18,"Mac %s",k);` -> `snprintf(mac, sizeof(mac), "Mac %s", k);`

Answer (score 0):

This would work (try it):

```
unsigned char array[6] = "abc";
```

but as you basically do this:

```
unsigned char array[6] = { 0x00, 0x0c, 0x2a, 0xab, 0x0f, 0x3c };
...
printf("%s", array);
```

you are actually printing a string of size 0. Remember that strings are NUL terminated.

Using variable number of arguments here is pointless.
You probably want this:

```
void fun(int x, unsigned char array[])
{
  char mac[28];
  snprintf(mac, sizeof(mac), "Mac %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5]);
  printf("Final mac is %s\n", mac);
}
```

or this:

```
void fun(int x, unsigned char array[])
{
  char mac[28];
  char hex[4];

  snprintf(mac, sizeof(mac), "Mac");

  for (int i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
  {
    sprintf(hex, " %02x", array[i]);
    strcat(mac, hex);
  }

  printf("Final mac is %s\n", mac);
}
```